# How to choose between 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu using a bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit, bootloader, 32-bit, boot-partition

Alright, so on an external hard drive, I plan to make multiple Ubuntu installations. As some computers do not mesh well with trying to use a different hierarchy as far as I can understand, how can I make a bootloader on the said external hard drive to support being able to choose between 64-bit and 32-bit?

Here's the partitioning game plan I have drawn out:

Not-bootable: FAT32 - 830GB "ObsidianWin"
Bootable: ext4 - 50GB "Obsidian32"
Bootable: ext4 - 50GB "Obsidian64"
Swap space: swap - 2GB

Total usable space: 932GB

If there needs to be another partition for the bootloader, then the FAT32 can get shrinked - I really don't mind/care, since the ObsidianWin partition is basically for storage.

Comment: I would recommend making a dedicated grub partition at the start of your dist to choose between the OSs, so that neither of them is booting the other. http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/grub/grubpartition.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Ubuntu bootloader (GRUB2) can boot any OS, 32 and 64bit. For example, if you install Ubuntu12.04 32bit and Ubuntu12.10 64bit or your disk, the GRUB menu will let you choose to boot "Ubuntu12.04" or "Ubuntu12.10".
2. If your computer is 32bit, you can't install any 64bit system on it
3. If your computer is 64bit, you can install 32bit systems and 64bit systems, but 64bit systems will manage better your hardware.

Comment: Alright, I guess from here, Google's my friend. Thanks, though. At least you pointed me in the right direction.